# How do I delete my account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Can someone help me or explain to me how I can delete my account, I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 7):

If you clicked on the 'help' link and scrolled down to the 'account' section, you would see:

[How do I delete my account?](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)

Which looks a little something like this:

[image]